# Notepad++ Regex Replace Makeshift Footnotes format With Proper Markdown format

Tags: regex, markdown, notepad++

In Word, I had to convert my footnotes to lines appearing at the end of each file to able to make changes in formatting. Some macro I found online was using braces and I ended up using also highlighting so I can see easily where my footnotes used to be. In this way, I have the following strings twice in my documents in the main text and also at the end of each document, sort of like makeshift endnotes.

```
=={1}==
.
.
.
=={99}==
```

I want to be able to match those instances in the text and convert them to proper markdown now. The problem is that the in-text format

```
[^1], [^2], etc.
```

will be different from what needs to come at the bottom with a semi-colon added:

```
[^1]:
```

etc.

So I'm guessing I'll have to live with replacing my old formatting with the new ones with semi-colons and deleting the semi-colons individually while I edit/clean up my text in the future. Without adding the semi-colon, it won't work.

My question is how to use the regex to match the two-digit strings with braces and equation marks.

This

```
==(\{d{1,2}\})==
```

did not work.

Also, as I am no pro, I would need the replacement as well. It probably will be

```
[^($1)]:
```

I reckon. Apparently, the equal mark doesn't have to be escaped.

Current format:

...some text...makeshift footnote in the format of

```
=={one- or two-digit number with no spaces in between}==
```

For example,

```
=={1}==

=={23}==
```

etc.

Desired result for all occurences recursively:

```
[^1]:
```

.
.
.

```
[^99]:
```

The markdown format is single square brackets with a caret and a number, also a semi-colon with the actual footnotes. Usually the number goes up to 42-45 maximum but it doesn't matter, the two digit regex is needed. As I said, the semi-colon will be needed in all instances.

Cheers

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73520972/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just some errors in your regex, you forget to escaped the `d` for digit, it should be `\d` and the capture group must not include the curly braces.

Use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `=={(\d{1,2})}==`
- Replace with: `[^$1]:`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
=={             # literally
(\d{1,2})       # group 1, 1 or 2 digits
}==             # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I have no Wrap Around under Find in Files tab in Linux Notepad++ (latest Snap version) (I need replacements for documents in all subfolders), but it works (under the other tab Wrap Around was ticked, by default, I reckon).
Thanks for the explanation as well. I understand now. I wasn't sure about where the normal brackets should go, either.
Cheers